# Maximum Spirit regeneration

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I want to try a build (for fun, not practical use) with maximum Spirit regen—what items and skills should I equip? What is the maximum possible rate of Spirit regeneration once all of these perks are in use?

Comment: I've updated the build to include dual wielded fists and a passive skill I overlooked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Fist of Az'Turrasq**(fist weapon) can roll up to **2.33** Spirit Per Second.
**The Demon Hand**(fist weapon) can roll up to **2** per second.
**The Madstone**(spirit stone) can roll up to **2.33** per second.

That puts us at **6.66** per second from gear.

**The Chain of Resonance Passive** gives **2** per second whil a mantra is active.

**The Mantra of Healing** with the **Circular Breathing Rune** gives you **3** per second.

So as far as I can tell, the max maximum spirit regen, disregarding Spirit Generator skills is 11.66 points per second.

Now, the listed monk fists attack 1.40 times per second. With the 15% dual wield bonus this you can attack 1.61 times per second. So 6 spirit per attack from Spirit Generators gives you **9.66** per second assuming you are attacking as fast as possible. This does not include any +% attack speed you may have, but I'm not sure how to find the max you could have on gear with the Spirit Regen Items.

**The Breath of Heaven** skill with **Infused With Light** rune will double this amount to **19.32 spirit per second**.

So with this build, you are guaranteed a maximum of **30.98 spirit per second**.

Please note that some skill runes will increase the spirit gained from an attack when you   crit, so realistically if you have this exact build you will be able to average more per second depending on your crit chance.

Other items to consider:

- Holy beacon
- Xephirian amulet
- Inna's set

Comment: 1.40 * 115% = 1.19 attacks per second? Shouldn't it be more like 1.71; making for a faster spirit gen

Comment: @Alok You're right. I was thinking backwards.

Comment: @Alok I was thinking seconds per attack haha.

Comment: There's another skill or two that adds spirit regen, plus you can always add in the Heal skill that increases regen per attack

Comment: @Domocus I believe I've accounted for every skill now.

Comment: Update, Inna's set items give spirit regeneration; plus a bonus if you have 3 of them.